# Make large, complex data table screen-reader friendly and 508 compliant

Tags: html, html-table, screen-readers, section508

I'm working with a very large HTML table. It is properly structured using `thead`, `th`, `scope=""`, etc. The `thead` has, for example, 7 header rows of nested columns and 180 columns across.

What are the recommended methods for making this sort of table 508 compliant and screen-reader friendly? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Each table header has to have an `id`, then each cell that has multiple table headers, use the `headers` attribute to link to ids.

The order of the `id`s in the `headers` is important, so think how you'd want the user to hear the data.